# Push notifications on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, push-notification

We've recently converted our project from eclipse to android studio.
The Parse library is added to the project and is defined in the build.gradle dependencies segment:

[image]

Now, pushing the notifications works perfectly fine on the version compiled in eclipse (the testing is done via https://www.parse.com).
Once converted to android studio, though, I can find the device on parse.com, but when I try to send a message through it, I get 0 notifications sent. Is there anything else I should do, or more information I should supply? I'm getting the feeling I didn't install the Parse library correctly, but I'm not sure 100% that this is what's causing it.

Comment: I struggled with parse too in android studio.. I tried loads if diff things in the end i gave up and went with pushbots instead. They are really helpful and u can chat to some one from
There if u struggle.. Plus it has helpful tutorials and the source code 2. Worked first try.

Comment: actually you already got compile fileTree() (line 4), remove line  23 and see what happen, i don't think it will fix your problem but just try.

Comment: @Krit Yea, I tried that too, the result is the same...

Comment: What about other require import for parse.com like bolt?

Comment: Well, basically I tried that too. Let's say I replaced line 23 with:
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

Now I can't compile because I'm getting:
Error:Execution failed for task ':<project_name>:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2